# How to detect the width and height of a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I'm looking to detect the width and height of an image and pass those dimensions into the following code:

```
   UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 5, imgView.size.width, imgView.size.width)];
```

Either there's something wrong with my syntax or this the wrong way to go about doing this. Any help would be great,
thanks

Comment: Both size arguments to `CGRectMake` are the width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
UIImage *someImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
UIImageView *someImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:someImage];
someImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, someImage.size.width, someImage.size.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the size of an image from the `UIImage` `size` property. Maybe something like:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 5, img.size.width, img.size.width)];
```

Or you can just:

```
UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
```

and it'll be sized automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is no width or height for the image view as you've just alloced and initialised it. The initWithFrame initialisation methods requires a float value, so you can't query imgView to return a value for the width and height yet as its yet to be determined.

I usually would use the initialiser initWithImage. Then modify the width and height of the imageview after initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

if you Want to set Maximum Width or Height then try this Code. it will control the size as well as you can set frame of image view dynamically.

```
CGSize size = image.size;

// Here Maximum width of image is 220 

    if (size.width > 220)
    {
        size.height /= (size.width / 220);
        size.width = 220;
    }
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
imageView.image = image;

// For layer mask or round corner

imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```